# Inheritance not working in JS?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Getting this error:

```
    this.parent.Thing is not a function
this.parent.Thing(x,y);
```

Heres the code.

```
[Break On This Error] this.parent.Thing(x,y); 

//Thing class start
            function Thing(x, y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            Thing.prototype.setX = function(newX){
                this.x = newX;
            }

            Thing.prototype.setY = function(newY){
                this.y = newY;
            }

            Thing.prototype.getX = function(){
                return this.x;
            }

            Thing.prototype.getY = function(){
                return this.y;
            }
            //Thing class end


            //player start
            Player.prototype = new Thing(); 
            Player.prototype.constructor=Player;       // Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal 
            Player.prototype.parent = Thing.prototype;

            function Player(x, y){ 
                this.parent.Thing(x,y);
            } 

            //player end


            var player = new Player(100,100);
```

Comment: got it from here: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: Avoid emulating classical Java like inheritance. you can call a constructor like that. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
this.parent.constructor.call(this,x,y);
```

You want to call the parent's constructor but have it apply to the "this" object. You can also use Thing directly, if you don't mind hard-coding the relationship:

```
Thing.call(this,x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating classical inheritance at all costs! It makes little sense in most situations when you can take the prototyped and/or functional approach to any problem.

The best approach is creating a composition situation to have each player have a, coords object that has gets/sets for x and y.

Comment: Object composition, closure's, mixin's and [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) are your friend. The prototype is over-rated.

Comment: @Raynos How much are you getting paid for your _ envangelism? :P

Comment: I strongly second closures over ANY of the other options, and I agree prototyping is over-rated, I only use it personally for extension methods on system types.

Comment: @IvoWetzel I'm not. Check the node.js popular downloads. `_` is at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Position = function(x,y) {
    var x = x;
    var y = y;
    if (Object.defineProperty) {
         Object.defineProperty(this, "x", {
             "enumerable": true,
             "get": function() { return x; }
         });
         Object.defineProperty(this, "y", {
             "enumerable": true,
             "get": function() { return y; }
         });
    } else {
        this.getX = function() { return x; }
        this.getY = function() { return y; }
    }
}

var Player = function(x,y) {
    _.extend(this, new Position(x,y));
}
```

Here we use a object composition instead of inheritance. Alternatively you can delegate and have Player take a private position object.

Also I recommend the use of `Object.defineProperty` for using getters and setters internally. It's like a C# `Property`.

[`_.extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)